# display image from database on page load in servlet

Tags: servlets

I would like to show an image when the page loads in a servlet. Considering that this page is an html page, I don't really understand how the image to be displayed can be mentioned programatically(say, for example database.

Had it been a servlet, I would have just done something like the following which shows an image once the button is clicked. But how do I do the same for an html?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");

          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

          out.print("<HTML>");
          out.print("<HEAD><TITLE>Upload Image</TITLE></HEAD>");
          out.print("<BODY>");

          out.print("<img src='images/imagethree.jpg' alt='image' />");
          out.print("<img src='images/imageone.jpg' alt='image' />");
          out.print("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"select\">");

          out.print("</BODY>");
          out.print("</HTML>");
          out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but you can retrieve image from database at the time of init() or by using some super calling statements in doget() method like(super or this()) and after that you can assign the image.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your folder structure is something like this:

```
|_ Web Contents
    |_ images
    |    |_ a.png
    |_ WEB-INF
```

And your `Context Path` is `SampleWebApp`. following image tag will show the picture:

```
<img src="/SampleWebApp/images/a.png">
```

Comment: Ali Sepheri, thanks for the reply.
But my question is, how I can specify the image name programatically and instead of hardcoding. Since this is during page load and before clicking any button, I assume this should be in html. But how can I read from a database and show the image in a html page. Is it possible to do this using javascript?

Comment: @IAMTubby: You just need to put the dynamic image name instead of fix image name.